# how to set size of doctrine choice widget from form/filter class

Tags: doctrine, widget, symfony1

To get around customising autogenerated forms, I need to set the "size" attribute on a doctrinechoice widget. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your form class :

```
$this->widgetSchema['your_choice_field'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(
  array(),   // you have to fill this array with your option (model, multiple, expanded ...)
  array('size' => 5)  // Attributes array here you can set attribute that will appear on the element
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Cheers for that reminder. I ended up using $this->widgetSchema['field']->setAttribute('size',6);